# Проблема в группировке отображения меток xticks в seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Мне необходимо сделать 15 столбчатых диаграмм с помощью Seaborn [image: дан вот такой датафрейм]

```
df_conversion = {'conv': {('Excel Базовый',
   'Основной функционал Excel (продолжение)'): 0.9475982532751092,
  ('Excel Базовый', 'Формулы и функции Excel. Введение'): 0.9802955665024631,
  ('Excel Базовый',
   'Формулы и функции Excel. Продолжаем работать с формулами'): 0.8914728682170543,
  ('Excel Базовый',
   'Формулы и функции Excel. Более сложные формулы'): 0.9834983498349835,
  ('Excel Базовый',
   'Формулы и функции Excel. Работа с ошибками, проверка данных'): 0.9740740740740741,
  ('Excel Базовый', ' Визуализация данных Excel'): 0.9834710743801653,
  ('Excel Базовый', 'Сводные таблицы Excel'): 1.01,
  ('Excel Базовый', 'Экзаменационная работа '): 1.0268817204301075,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Синтаксис языка'): 0.9253996447602132,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Объекты и классы'): 0.8758782201405152,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Числа, строки и даты'): 0.9625850340136054,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Массивы и коллекции'): 0.9310344827586207,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Наследование и полиморфизм'): 1.0115606936416186,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Тестирование и отладка'): 0.9875,
  ('Java-разработчик', 'Итоговая тема'): 1.105263157894737,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля', 'Синтаксис языка'): 0.9858657243816255,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля', 'Объекты и классы'): 0.9547511312217195,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля', 'Числа, строки и даты'): 1.08,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля', 'Массивы и коллекции'): 0.9636363636363636,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля',
   'Наследование и полиморфизм'): 0.9866666666666667,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля', 'Особенности ООП в Java'): 1.0833333333333333,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля',
   'Исключения, отладка, тестирование и логгирование'): 0.8918918918918919,
  ('Java-разработчик c нуля', 'Работа с файлами и сетью'): 1.0,
  ('JavaScript с нуля', 'Основы'): 0.95,
  ('JavaScript с нуля', 'Функции'): 0.9844357976653697,
  ('PHP-разработчик с 0 до PRO. Часть 1',
   'Структура управления данными. Базовые концепции PHP 7'): 0.8553054662379421,
  ('PHP-разработчик с 0 до PRO. Часть 1',
   'Протокол HTTP/HTTPS'): 1.3076923076923077,
  ('PHP-разработчик с 0 до PRO. Часть 1', 'Пользовательские функции'): 1.024,
  ('PHP-разработчик с 0 до PRO. Часть 1', 'Файлы и каталоги'): 1.1375,
  ('SMM-маркетолог от А до Я',
   'Разработка стратегии продвижения в Social Media'): 0.8181818181818182,
  ('SMM-маркетолог от А до Я',
   'Разработка креативных решений'): 0.9482758620689655,
  ('SMM-маркетолог от А до Я', 'Дизайн для не дизайнеров'): 0.5643564356435643,}}
df_conversion = = pd.DataFrame(df_conversion).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'title', 'level_1': 'module_title'})
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_conversion, col = 'title', height= 6, aspect= 2, col_wrap=1 )
g.map(sns.barplot, 'module_title', 'conv')
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=2)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Но все названия меток по оси Х (module_title) не соответствуют своим title, у каждого графика одинаковые метки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот пример того, как должно получится
[image: чтобы получилось вот так]

Comment: пример исходных данных приведите в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog Первый скриншот исходный датафрейм или имеется в виду, прикрепить сам файл csv?

Comment: ну если вы не надеетесь, что кто-то будет перепечатывать ваш скриншот, то лучше, конечно, прикрепить файл

Comment: @strawdog Добавил часть данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я подозреваю, что для такого набора данные решение с FacetGrid не подойдет. Вам данные нужно сгруппировать, что частично делает FacetGrid, но sns.barplot не поймет такую группировку, и будет выводить графики неправильно. а plt.bar поймет, но все равно будет использовать общую ось абсцисс.
Поэтому я бы советовал группировать данные явно, и каждую группу выводить в виде графика:

```
df_conversion =  pd.DataFrame(df_conversion).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'title', 'level_1': 'module_title'})


fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 42))
idx = 0
for i, k in df_conversion.groupby("title"):
    ax = axs.ravel()[idx]
    g = sns.barplot(k, x="module_title", y="conv", ax=ax)
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=2)
    g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
    ax.set_title(i)
    idx+=1

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]